# Kafka member id store in ZK?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Does anybody know that the consumer's Member ID was stored in zookeeper or Kafka?How can I delete it or send Leave Group Request to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is idea of groupId for consumers.

https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181/path  --group your_group_id --delete
```

In Kafka 0.8 offsets were stored in Zookeeper. You can find them if you browser zookeeper tree.
In Kafka 0.9 offsets were migrated to kafka. Separate topic with compaction. See more http://www.slideshare.net/jjkoshy/offset-management-in-kafka